# 100% width in px's

Tags: html, mobile, width

I have a container for the header which contains an image and a series of links `Home` `about` etc.

I want this to stretch 100% of the page width so I can center the inner divs and align the whole page. easy enough width:100%. But 100% width on a mobile or app isn't enough space for my links to fit on and thus gets cut off.

Right now I have a container `width:1950px;` simply because that stretches across the screen and works alright but it is no way a good way to do it. It creates a side scroll bar at the bottom.

So basically I want to find out the width of the screen and give it a more 'static' width.

Or any other ways around it will be great.

Comment: You want it to stretch `100%` of page width, but that isn't always enough space, am I right? but you don't want a scrollbar? Are you thinking of dynamically changing it based on width? You can do this with jQuery.

Comment: I would very much recommend having multiple style sheets so you can differentiate between the mobile version and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good guys. Played with a bit and eventually made the outer container 100% and the inner container a set width margin left/right auto. Had to do a bit to get my background back and was fiddly at first but managed to solve it. Thanks anyways. Was more simple of a solution then I let on.